# There are different results between subset code in R

Tags: r, subset

The results of:

`BB= RB[RB$Rep, %in% c(“1”,”3”)]` and
`Bb=subset(RB,Rep ==c(“1”,”3”) )`
are different.

Please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Second code possible is taking only the first element. Instead you should try: `Bb=subset(RB,Rep ==c(“1”) | Rep == c(”3”) ) `

Comment: Thank you!  But I would like to know why the result is different when I enter these two code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post code samples as photos. Just copy the text and paste it into your question. Then select it and press the "{ }" button to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `==` the comparison is done in a sequential order.

Consider this example :

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = c(1:3, 3:1))
df
#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
#3 3 3
#4 4 3
#5 5 2
#6 6 1
```

When you use :

```
subset(df, b == c(1, 3))
#  a b
#1 1 1
#4 4 3
```

1st value of `b` is compared with 1, 2nd with 3. Now as you have vector of shorter length, the values are recycled meaning 3rd value is again compared to 1, 4th value with 3 and so on until end of the dataframe. Hence, you get row 1 and 4 as output here.

When you use `%in%` it checks for either 1 or 3 is present in `b`. So it selects all the rows where value 1 or 3 is present in `b`.

```
subset(df, b %in% c(1, 3))

#  a b
#1 1 1
#3 3 3
#4 4 3
#6 6 1
```